# Alinhamento de elementos na página

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em amarelo temos tag `main` e em azul temos o `aside` ambos como `display: inline-block` gostaria de saber o porque o `aside` não se posiciona a partir do topo.

```
<main>
        <section>
            <article>
                <img src="../mtKTM1024x600.jpg">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <img src="../mtKTM1024x600.jpg">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </main><aside><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></aside>
```

Comment: devido as 3 "divs" fazerem parte de uma só coluna. Onde a div azul entende que o "topo" já está sendo preenchido, porém, visivelmente as divs amarelas tem uma largura limitada, por isso trás a impressão de que há um "erro" de CSS.

Comment: O ideal seria o uso do [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) em conjunto com as propriedades [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) e [grid-template-rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) onde você consegue dividir a página em **2 ou mais colunas** onde na primeira coluna será preenchida com as "divs" amarelas e na segunda coluna será preenchida com a div azul (*por padrão ela vai entender que só ela faz parte daquela fração e coloca-se ao topo*)

Comment: Vale ressaltar que deve-se respeitar as dimensões, pois numa página e/ou resolução que tenha 100px de largura, sendo que sua div amarela tem 90px de largura, mais a div azul com 50px, nada será ajustado de forma automática (*supondo que as amarelas tendo uma width de 70px e a azul com width de 30px tudo de enquadra direitinho*)

Comment: Pq deveria alinhar ao topo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Eu sugiro que..

você fizesse o uso do [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) pois facilita na hora de organizar os elementos na página.

Fiz um pequeno código de exemplo, pois na sua pergunta está faltando informações. Não deixe de ver [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

---

No código abaixo faço uso do `display: grid` em conjunto com a propriedade [`grid-template-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) onde divido a página (*neste caso a tag body*) em **1 fração**, ou seja, duas colunas de `1fr`

Portanto, **DIGO** a tag `main` que ela pertence a coluna 1 e que a tag `aside` pertence a coluna 2

> [image] .
>
> > Na imagem acima mostro uma ilustração no DevTools clara referente a essa divisão

```css
body {
  display: grid; /* ao invés do "inline-block" ou "block" */
  grid-template-column: repeat(2, 1fr); /* aqui separo a coluna em 2 frações */
}

main {
  grid-column: 1; /* digo que a tag main pertence a coluna 1 do display grid*/
}

aside {
  grid-column: 2; /* digo que a tag aside pertence a coluna 2 do display grid*/
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}

section > article {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet nulla mollitia, soluta, nisi nam similique ex suscipit in ipsa corrupti libero, repudiandae debitis at? Totam, illo earum. Quae, aspernatur dicta.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet nulla mollitia, soluta, nisi nam similique ex suscipit in ipsa corrupti libero, repudiandae debitis at? Totam, illo earum. Quae, aspernatur dicta.</p>
  </article>
</section>
</main>
<aside>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel aliquid repudiandae debitis laborum sint deleniti quasi ea quos, velit illum inventore sunt, totam assumenda commodi. Accusantium ratione atque ea sed?</p>
</aside>
```

Assim como o **CSS Grid Layout** existe também o [CSS Flexible Box Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) (*ou **Flexbox***) vale apena da uma olhada, com ele você pode ta fazendo uso de algumas dessas propriedades abaixo

- [align-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)
- [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)
- [align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)
- [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

e entre outros..

Comment: Pq a "sua opnião" deveria ser melhor que a "opinião" de outra pessoa ou até mesmo o ideal, nesse caso?

Comment: É pq a sua resposta fica mt subjetiva quando começa com a frase **"Na minha opinião.."**..

Comment: @Sam Na sua opinião, o que você acha que devo fazer? remover a frase? reformulá-la?

Comment: Vc pode **propor** uma solução... e eu, particularmente, acho que o CSS Grid seria uma péssima solução. Ninguém usa isso não.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126933/discussion-between-gleisin-dev-and-sam).